# Why there's a not operator in programming?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, logical-operators

Regardless of the programming language, Why there's a `not` operator while I may compare the expression with `false` and that will do the work needed.

For example, if I have a function called `valid` that returns `boolean` (true if valid and false if not) and I want to check if it's not valid then I will write it like this:

```py
if not valid():
   print("Not Valid")
```

While I can simply check if valid equals false like this:

```py
if valid() == false:
   print("Not Valid")
```

Comment: In Python, they're not strictly equal. A thing may be false-y without equalling false.

Answer (score 3):

**not** is shorter and it is easier to understand. **if not valid** is simpler and closer to English than **if valid equals false**